# Writing TFRecords in batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

All documentations I found regarding TFRecords are generating `tf.train.Example()`s one by one, and writing them using

```
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWrite(path)
ex = generate_example(features)  # Returns tf.train.Example() instance
writer.write(ex.SerializeToString())
```

Since I'm dealing with very big data, I know that I'll pay a high overhead price for writing examples separately

Is there any way to write multiple `tf.train.Example()` to a TFRecord at once?

Comment: Were you able to finally solve this problem? ;)

Comment: Never found an answer for this @neel g

Answer (score -1):

Since TFRecord is just a serialized version of your original data bundled with some extra information I am not sure you can accomplish what you are asking. Some questions that comes in my mind:

1. How are you supposed to write to a file multiple examples
   simultaneously?
2. And if you succeed in the above goal (deal with all the concurrent issues etc) tensorflow will still read them in the same way: serially so I am not sure what's the benefit here.
3. Also, TFRecord are supposed to be written once and used many times. Meaning they are not the product of any training or a process that may change in the future. They are supposed to be the input to your model. So, regardless of the effort to create them it's one time job. How big are your data. And in this case I think you will have more trouble dealing with them in the training procedure than writing them in TFRecords.
4. A (naive) workaround I can think of is to create multiple TFRecord files simultaneously. This way for example you can speed up the writing of TFRecord if that's what is bothering you. You can then read them using a list of records instead of a single TFRecord file. Of course in this case tensorflow will read them serially once again.

Comment: Well, the output if `ex.SerializeToString()` is a string, so instead of of writing one by one, I'd rather join the strings beforehand (in the acceptable format which I don't know what it is) and write them to disk in batches. This is not parallel writing - its batching

Comment: Maybe I wrongfully assumed its obvious, but most of the time is spent in the writing, so I prefer to write 1000 examples at once, instead of writing single lines 1000 times